# How to make a react component call a function from another Material UI Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

There's two components the Drawer and the AppBar. App Bar has a menu button, and it must fire an event that opens the drawer, I'm stuck in how to make this, i tried to add the *"onClick={toggleDrawer('left', true)}"* line that exists in the button from Drawer to the IconButton in the TopBar, and this went wrong.  How to say to the TopBar that "toggleDrawer" is a function from MyDrawer?

MyDrawer.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
export default function MyDrawer() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        top: false,
        left: false,
        bottom: false,
        right: false,
    });
    type DrawerSide = 'top' | 'left' | 'bottom' | 'right';
    const toggleDrawer = (side: DrawerSide, open: boolean) => (
        event: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent,
    ) => {
        if (
            event.type === 'keydown' &&
                ((event as React.KeyboardEvent).key === 'Tab' ||
                (event as React.KeyboardEvent).key === 'Shift')
            ) {
        return;
    }
    setState({ ...state, [side]: open });
    }; 
//drawer list of links
    return (
            <div>
                {/* <Button onClick={toggleDrawer('left', true)}>Open Left</Button>  */}          
                <Drawer open={state.left} onClose={toggleDrawer('left', false)}>
                    {sideList('left')}
                </Drawer>            
            </div>
        );
```

TopBar.tsx

```
import MyDrawer from '../Drawer/Drawer'
export default function TopBar() {
const renderDrawer = (
    <OlimpoDrawer/>
  );
return (
    <div className={classes.grow}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="abrir menu"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
//Toolbar features
</Toolbar>
      </AppBar>      
      {renderDrawer}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me understand your question. You want the `IconButton` to do the same thing like `Button`, commented, in `MyDrawer`.

If that's what you want. You should create and pass the function from `TopBar` into `MyDrawer`. `toggleDrawer` should be defined in `TopBar` and then put it into the `onClick` of both `IconButton` and `Button` which you had commented.

```
     setState(preState => ({ ...preState, [side]: open }));
```

Note: `setState` by this way is better.

Comment: This assumes `MyDrawer` is a descendant of `TopBar` so you can pass `toggleDrawer` down from `TopBar` to `MyDrawer` if that's what @吳約南 had in mind.

Comment: Thank you @stackoverflow-newbie improve my sentences.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make a react component call a function from another Material UI Typescript

```
//...
const toggleDrawer = (side: DrawerSide, open: boolean) => (event: React.KeyboardEvent | React.MouseEvent) => {
   if (/* ... */)
    ) {
        return;
    }
    setState({ ...state, [side]: open });
};
```

Because `toggleDrawer` depends on `setState` which is scoped only inside the `MyDrawer` functional component so it needs to stay inside `toggleDrawer`, it's not possible to do something like `export TopBar` the function for `TopBar` to use directly.

If all you need is for somewhere to store the open states and for other components to share a callback function, I suggest either use a higher component (which they both share) or Redux to store `MyDrawer`'s open state.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I though more "out of the box" and made the easiest

In MyDrawer.tsx I changed the render creating a menu button just like the drawer one

```
return (
        <div>
            <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="abrir menu"
            onClick={toggleDrawer('left', true)}
            > 
                <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>            
            <Drawer open={state.left} onClose={toggleDrawer('left', false)}>
                {sideList('left')}
            </Drawer>            
        </div>
    );
}
```

In TopBar.tsx

```
<div className={classes.grow}>
      <AppBar position="static">      
        <Toolbar>
          <MyDrawer/>
          {/* <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="abrir menu"            
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton> */}
```